# Problem evaluating NULL in an IIF statement (Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba, null, iif-function

Item in the recordset rstImportData("Flat Size") is = Null

With that, given the following statement:

```
IIF(IsNull(rstImportData("Flat Size")), Null, cstr(rstImportData("Flat Size")))
Result: Throws error 94: Invalid use of Null
```

If I change the statement by removing the type conversion upon a false comparison:

```
IIF(IsNull(rstImportData("Flat Size")), Null, 0)
Result: Null
```

It returns Null as it should have the first time.  It appears that I cannot do a type conversion in an IIF if the value passed in should ever be null even if it passes an IIF test, it still attempts to evaluate it at both the true and false answer.  The only reason I'm using IIF like this is because I have a 25 line comparison to compare data from an Import against a matching record in a database to see if I need to append the prior to history.

Any thoughts?  The way data is imported there will be null dates and where the spreadsheet import is in a string format I must convert either side to the other to compare the values properly but if either side is null this exception occurs :(

*EDIT*
Example of why I was using IIF (and considering using a universal function)

```
If master("one") <> import("one") Or _
   master("two") <> import("two") Or _
   master("date") <> import("date") Or _  //import("date") comes from a spreadsheet, it comes in as string, CAN be a null value
   master("qty") <> import("qty") Or _    //import("qty") comes from spreadsheet, comes in as a string can CAN be null
   master("etc") <> import("etc") Then

....stuff....

End If
```

This code expands for roughly 20 columns to compare in the database.  I would prefer to check as part of the statement.  I can think of a bunch of solutions but they involve adding much more code.  If that is the case power to it, however I'm not one to give in so easily.

Options I see are

- Creating temp vars to do the work prior to comparing and using these new vars instead of the recordset
- Creating an object to pass the record into to preformat and work with, though extra work would provide this functionality to each import type since there are different files with similar fields

I'm here for ideas, and I'm open to any interesting pieces that can be thrown my way as I get to decide how to do it I'm looking for the most reusable approach.

Comment: How about: cstr(rstImportData("Flat Size") & "") or simply: rstImportData("Flat Size") & ""

Comment: IIf() does not short circuit in code, and you're assuming it does. I really don't think anybody should use IIf() in code, anyway. Its purpose is to provide the functionality of If/Then/Else in expressions outside a code context.

Comment: Are you sure you need to coerce the result to a string value? Have you considered the Nz() function?

Comment: In one given case, its a string, the next its a date... if the date really is null it needs to remain that way, so I cannot give it a null case value in those events... certain cases of make approaches unique :\.  The problem is that im passing an evaluation into the IIF function... I have to evaluate it prior to passing... I'm still considering a function to use universally for these cases.  The if statement I'm using is over 20 lines of comparison, I need to evaluate all fields at once, IIF was an option per field where this type of output can be expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple expedient of changing the value to a string helps tremendously. The trick is that trimming a string which is NULL will get a null string. Which can then be operated on as if it wasn't a database null.
I frequently use the form:

```
CInt("0" & Trim(SomeVariant & " "))
```

To get a valid number without having to go through a bunch of hijinks. The null is a nonentity for this problem.

Comment: Interesting trick to parse a null into another datatype... I will test this with both '03 and '07 to use moving forward but its a pretty interesting idea, this is the stuff I like to learn :) thx for the tip.  My original attempt in the IIF involved using IIF with IsDate or IsNumeric, in the case that it doesn't fit those parameters after conversion then it remains null otherwise I can push the new value into the database.

Comment: This didn't work well in early versions of .NET. It works wonderfully in later versions.

Comment: what does .NET have to do with this question?

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you described is the standard way IIf operates under VBA.  This is part of what Access 2003 Help says about it:

"**IIf** always evaluates both ***truepart*** and ***falsepart***, even though it returns only one of them. Because of this, you should watch for undesirable side effects. For example, if evaluating ***falsepart*** results in a division by zero error, an error occurs even if ***expr*** is **True**."

However, if you use an IIf statement in a query, evaluation short circuits after ***truepart*** when ***expr*** is **True** --- ***falsepart*** is not evaluated in that case.  Unfortunately this information is not useful for you ... unless you can incorporate a query into your comparison.

I don't know of any other way to avoid your error with IIf.  I would try appending the Excel data into a table whose structure matches that of the table you will compare against, thereby eliminating the need to do a string conversion at the same time you do the comparison.

Comment: Given this behavior I may make a function that evaluates a given type that I would pass in to eliminate the need for an IIF in this huge If statement I am maintaining...  Ive got the weekend to come up with a great answer, definitely a wall I didn't expect to hit.

Comment: You're working with a recordset, so this is in code, so just use a plain old If/Then/Else block.